# GPS trace every 2 minutes (requestLocationUpdates, Timer or Handler)

Tags: android, timer, gps, handler

I am developing an application that needs to save every 2 minutes a trace of the GPS position of the device.
The first attempt was to use **requestLocationUpdates**:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 120000L, 0f, this);
```

For testing I use a **Samsung Galaxy Mini (Android 2.3.5)**.
If I do the test in debug mode with the USB cable connected, everything works perfect, every two minutes I get the position.
The problem is when I unplug the USB and go to the street and testing. This way I get a GPS position every second. This is too much.
After much review my code I have decided to use a Timer:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Location loc=getLastBestLocation(Activity.this);
        GpsStore.save(loc);
    }   
}, 120000L, 120000L);
```

Again, if testing the application in debug mode with the USB cable everything goes right.
If I go out and get tested if the application is in the foreground all goes well, if the application is in the background the TimerTask does not run every 2 minutes, it is stopped and when the application returns to the foreground suddenly runs all times the TimerTask it had executed normally. But everything quickly in about 1 second.

Again after much review my code, I decided to use instead of Timer Handler:

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                                    Location loc=getLastBestLocation(Activity.this);
                                    GpsStore.save(loc);

                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                handler.postDelayed(this,120000L);
           }
        };
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 120000L);
```

As always everything works fine in debug mode with USB. What happens now when I do the test on the street is that when the application is in the foreground by handler does not run exactly every 2 minutes sometimes do it every 4 other times in 1, but when the application is in background in order Runnable using the Handler does not run every 2 minutes, never runs.

I would use just requestLocationUpdates but is called every second.
I need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates`, you'll see that the `minTime` argument is only taken as a hint.  The real LocationProvider can give updates sooner than you specify.  I would recommend that you also set the `minDistance` value.  Set it to at least 100m.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that `minTime` is a hint. That is why I tried to do using `Timer` and `Handler`. I need the GPS coordinates with a fixed time interval. This interval must always be fulfilled. Where I have written that the interval is 2 minutes maybe 30 minutes but the important thing is that the interval is completed accurately. It must be impossible that sometimes works and sometimes not.

Comment: I've done a similar thing logging positions.  I simply used the AlarmManager and had it send a PendingIntent to a Service component.  This happens whether or not your activity is in the foreground or not.

Comment: put this comment as and answer. That way people will vote (or not) for it as a good answer. About AlarmManager, thanks, I'll try what you say.